# Are inline scripts executed on the controller or agent

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

From my understanding, during a pipeline run, all groovy is executed on the controller. Because of this, it's recommended that network calls should be delegated to bash or some other scripting/programming language so that network requests will be executed on the agent.

Do inline scripts execute on the agent on the controller?

For example:
Do

`sh "curl some-url.com"`

and

`sh "./script-which-calls-curl.sh"`

behave the same?

Answer (score 0):

Whether a script runs on the controller or not is independent of whether is is inline or not, it depends on the context of the `sh` step: it requires an explicit agent, that determines the agent the script will actually run on, which can be the controller.

This minimal pipeline will error due to missing agent/node:

```
sh "echo hello"
```

instead you will need to wrap it into a `node` block (scripted pipeline) or select an appropriate agent (declarative):

```
// without any arguments any node/agent is taken
// in my setups this normally selects the controller
node {
    sh "echo hello"
}
```

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage "My Stage", {
            sh "echo hello"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For a declarative pipeline, if the script is called in a shared library function, does that make a difference?

Comment: The sh step behaves the same way in a shared library function, no difference there.